# A most delayed departure

Tags: riddle

> My first is in Britain, which once was called Great,
>   My second's in Boris, who's for sealing its fate.
>   My third is in Europe, where patience wears thin,
>   My fourth is in taxes, but not European!
>   My fifth is in Ireland, but not in the South
>   My sixth is in parliament, kept out of their house.
>   My whole's a fiasco, gone on now for years,
>   And the sorry conclusion will surely bring tears.

The answer is one word.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The word is

> Brexit

The first, second etc.

> refer to the nth letter in the word. So the first is B (found in "Britain", etc.) And the rest of the poem of course refers to various aspects of Brexit literally.

Comment: You might just be faster than Gareth when it comes to solving my modest puzzles!  I have to wait 10 minutes still to award you the tick I'm afraid.